# Print image inside html to be able to input the printed name through input field

Tags: php, image

so i have this php code which prints out image with text but i wish for it to display inside html tags like head title body but doing so image does not display if i put in html in the follow code

```
<?php
$yourname       = "Some Name";
$date           = date("Y-m-d");
$pos            = "2nd";
$image = imagecreatefrompng('certificate.png');
imagealphablending($image, true);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 150,0, 0);

// imagefttext("Image", "Font Size", "Rotate Text", "Left Position", "Top Position", "Font Color", "Font Name", "Text To Print");

imagefttext($image, 30, 0, 35, 154, $red, 'mono.ttf', $yourname);
imagefttext($image, 20, 0, 300, 206, $red, 'mono.ttf', $date);  
imagefttext($image, 20, 0, 78, 256, $red, 'mono.ttf', $pos);    

/* If you want to display the file in browser */


header('Content-type: image/png');
ImagePng($image);
imagedestroy($image);


/* if you want to save the file in the web server */


$filename = 'certificate_aadarsh.png';
ImagePng($image, $filename);
imagedestroy($image);

/* If you wnat the user to save the file */


$filename = 'certificate_aadarsh.png';
ImagePng($image,$filename);

header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: public, no-cache');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($filename);

imagedestroy($image);
$filename       = 'certificate_aadarsh.png';
ImagePng($image, $filename);
imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

i tried this way to be able to print text but nothing happens a blank page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    $yourname = $name;
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $pos = "2nd";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('certificate.png');
    imagealphablending($image, true);
    $red = imagecolorallocate($image, 150,0, 0);

    // imagefttext("Image", "Font Size", "Rotate Text", "Left Position", "Top Position", "Font Color", "Font Name", "Text To Print");

    imagefttext($image, 30, 0, 35, 154, $red, 'mono.ttf', $yourname);
    imagefttext($image, 20, 0, 300, 206, $red, 'mono.ttf', $date);  
    imagefttext($image, 20, 0, 78, 256, $red, 'mono.ttf', $pos);    

    /* If you want to display the file in browser */


    header('Content-type: image/png');
    ImagePng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);


    /* if you want to save the file in the web server */


    $filename = 'certificate_aadarsh.png';
    ImagePng($image, $filename);
    imagedestroy($image);

    /* If you wnat the user to save the file */


    $filename = 'certificate_aadarsh.png';
    ImagePng($image,$filename);

    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Cache-Control: public, no-cache');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile($filename);

    imagedestroy($image);
    $filename       = 'certificate_aadarsh.png';
    ImagePng($image, $filename);
    imagedestroy($image);
    }
    ?>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

anyone can help to make this work inside html and display the output image?

Comment: *"but i wish to be able to input the printed name through input field so how do i go about make it print whatsoever name i submit through form? – Lovelina"* - That, should have been posted in your question from the get go.

Comment: you r right im sorry about the question i will correct it now

Comment: @Fred-ii- u there mate?

Answer (score 1):

`<img src="yourphpimagefile.php?text=sometextfrominputfiled">`.

In your `imagefile.php`, get text as `$text = $_POST['text']`

Comment: but i wish to be able to input the printed name through input field so how do i go about make it print whatsoever name i submit through form?

Comment: this is not going to solve a bit of question anyhow, because that's the problem address by OP (he can't able to add html tags)

Comment: @Anant did you understand what i am talking about?

Comment: @Anant given what the OP stated "after the fact" and wanting to use a form, this answer (whoever downvoted it which was not me for one thing) did provide an initial solution.

Comment: @ AB Catella; that is not my downvote here. Edit: actually, I upvoted it.

Comment: but nothing prints

Comment: @Lovelina Please don't dump code in comments, which should have been part of your original posted question. You're making this very difficult for everyone and having A B's answer downvoted because of that.

Comment: Guys help me out please